# VSCODE: Unable to Authorize to an ORG

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, visualstudiocode

I'm having the same problem. For me, I'm not getting redirected to my salesforce Org. This is what I see in VSCode

12:22:15.474 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias DevOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername » Warning: force:auth:web:login is not a sfdx command. Did you mean auth:web:login? [y/n]: » Error: Run sfdx help force for a list of available commands. 12:22:21.923 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias DevOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 127

Salesforce Extension Pack: v50.13.0

Source: Salesforce CLI Integration (Extension)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a current regression [bug](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/811) in the Salesforce CLI latest version causing the issue.

For now, you can work around by running below in your vscode terminal

```
sfdx auth:web:login --setalias DevOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
```

Notice that now you need to use `sfdx auth:web:login` instead of `sfdx force:auth:web:login` for authorization.